# Can you scrape a Angular JS website

Tags: angularjs

This was marked **off-topic** but left on Stack Overflow in case someone else has this same question.

This may be out of scope but I was curious to know if you could scrape a Angular JS website?

If you can can someone point me to some good resources? I did some R & D but could not find any useful resources besides Phantom JS

Comment: I'm not sure if you figured a solution to do this but the simplest answer is to use `phantomjs` which is a headless browser that let's you script and fetch data using css selectors and do anything you want with it. http://phantomjs.org Let me know if you need further help.

P.S I'm not sure how this was voted off-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050746/web-scraping-how-to-access-content-rendered-in-javascript-via-angular-js#35050903

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer to this question is yes, it is possible, but not using traditional bots that only look at the raw textual content that they'd get in the HTTP response body and don't really interpret what a typical browser running JavaScript would see. Google does it (as of May 2014):
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html

If you have a bot that parses javascript and allows the normal http xhr requests to go out and get the actual data that populates a SPA, you can scrape an Angular site.

Comment: also useful info: http://thiagomarzagao.com/2013/11/17/webscraping-with-selenium-part-5/